# What is the meaning of this notation in the dual space definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

This is just about the clearest [definition of double dual space](http://yums.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Dual-Spaces.pdf) I have come across:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb R$. We know that a
>   finite-dimensional vector space $V$ is isomorphic to its dual space
>   $V^*$. This isomorphism is not ‘very nice’ because it depends on the
>   choice of basis. There is however one example of a ‘nice’ or natural
>   isomorphism between two vector spaces. This is an isomorphism between
>   a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and the dual space $V^{**}$ of
>   its dual $V^*.$ The space $V^{**}$ is called the double (or second)
>   dual of $V$. The elements of $V^{**}$ are linear functionals of linear
>   functionals.
>
> Let $v_0$ be a vector in $V$. For each $f \in V^*$, we write
>
> $$v_0^*(f)=f(v_0)$$
>
> In this formula, $v_0$ is fixed (in $V$) and $f$ is allowed to vary
>   (in $V^*$), so that the formula defines a function on $V^*$.

But I still don't get it. In part it might be the notation:

What is $v_0^*$ and how do you verbalize the notation? The quote defines $v_0$ as a vector in the original $V$ vector space. That is clear, although the need for the subindex $0$ is either just annoying or its meaning obscure. But there is never a definition of $v_0^*$. I presume it is something along the lines of the "vector being fed to $V^*$ from $V$" (?), but of course then comes the $(f)$, which is defined as a function... and the house of cards inside $v_0^*(f)=f(v_0)$ seems to collapse again.

Is this thing, $a_0^*(f)\in V^{**}?$

Asking for an example may be too much, but a deciphering of the notation would be a great starting point to start thinking about the concept.

---

> CONCLUSIONS (after the accepted answer, comments and additional
>   studying):

I initially asked

> how to "verbalize" $v_0^*(f)=f(v_0)$

meaning how to "unpack" this cluster... OK "Charlie Foxtrot" of super and sub-scripted notation in English. This is what I was thinking of as the ideal answer:

It means: Any given vector in $V$, for example, $v_0 \in V$, can be uniquely mapped to an element in $V^{**}$, corresponding to a functional **on** $V^*$ (that is a functional that eats functions in the space of $V^*$). This functional on $V^{*}$ can be called $v_0^*$.

That is to say, our new friend, $v_0^*$, belongs to $V^{**}$, but carries one single star because the star makes reference to what it "eats" $(V^{*})$, not where it lives $(V^{**}).$ The author kindly throws the subscript $0$ in $a_0^*$ just in case there was anyone still following at that point - poetic license like in Edgar Allan Poe's “All that we see or seem is but a dream within a dream.” But I digress. In any event, $a_0^*$ lives in the dual of the dual, and as any dual, it is a linear functional. So a function from a real vector space to $\mathbb R.$

The parenthesis, $(f)$ part $v_0^*(f)$, again is telling us that what goes into the functional $a_0^*(\text{here})$ is the functionals $(f)$ that live in $V^*$, sending $V\rightarrow \mathbb R.$ Redundant to have this $(f)$ when we already indicated the "diet" of $a_0^*(f)$ with the asterisk in the superscript? You bet. This part makes sense, though, much like $f(x)=\log x$ makes sense. What is annoying is not having suppressed the superscript $*$ in $a_0^*$. It could have been notated like $L_v(f)$, you know... $L$ for linear functional, $v\in V,$... very simple, but risking the cabalistic aroma of $a_0^*(f).$

OK. So on to the RHS of the equation, which is more of a definition, $:=f(v_0)$
is only uninspired at first glance, being deeply tricky at heart: you look at it and you may assume it the function of... $f(\color{red}{v_0}),$ but it's much more devilish... Here $v_0$ is fixed, and the actual variable is $\color{red}{f(\cdot)}.$

$v_0^*(f)=f(v_0)$ evaluates the functionals in $V^*$ **at** $v_0$, which remains fixed. So the functions of $V^*$ (dual space) are zipped through by the $a_0^*$ functional in $V^{**}$ one at a time, as it where, while $v_0\in V$ stays the same.

It is in this regard and *evaluation map*. So if can leave aside the cryptographic notation in the quoted paragraph, and call the function in $V^{**}$ something less obscure, $L_v(f)=f(v)$, where $f\in V^*$ and $v\in V$, we can look at it as a map $L_v: V^*\rightarrow \mathbb R$. Once $v$ is fixed, (let's bring out now the subscripts) to say, $v_0$, the function $L_{v_0}=f(v_0)$ is the evaluation function.

So how to verbalize this? Clearly ‘vee-nought-star' on $X^*.$ As in the answer.

It might be more straightforward to look at it as a [dual pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_pair#Example) or [bracket notation](http://cims.nyu.edu/~marques/US/LAIduality.pdf):

> If $V$ is ﬁnite dimensional there is a natural “bracketing map” $\phi
> > : V^∗ \times V \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $\phi:( f,v) \mapsto
> > ⟨f,v⟩.$ The expression $\langle f,v \rangle$ is linear in each
>   variable when the other is held ﬁxed. If $f$ is ﬁxed we get a linear
>   functional $v \mapsto f(v)$ on $V,$ but if we ﬁx $v$ the map $f
> > \mapsto \langle f,v \rangle$ is a linear map from $V^∗ \rightarrow
> > \mathbb R,$ and hence is an element $j(v) \in V^{∗∗} =( V^∗)^∗,$ the
>   “double dual” of $V.$

This last concept is nicely explained [here](https://youtu.be/pIEdt5gG9NA).

Comment: The subscript $0$ is not mathematically necessary. It is probably a cultural reference to the practice of denoting points that are kept constant ("points of reference") by $x_0$, $v_0$, $p_0$, etc. (and the point $v_0$ is being kept constant in the definition of $v_0^*$; the only "moving part"/variable is $f $).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes, thanks for confirming. I think I get it now, and I allowed myself some room for humor in what is otherwise the summary of quite of bit of studying, mainly to decipher what is, now, almost obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The displayed line *is* the definition of $v_0^*$. Each vector $v_0$ in $V$ determines a linear functional $v_0^*$ (which I read ‘vee-nought-star’) on $X^*$, i.e., an element $v_0^*$ of $V^{**}$. This $v_0^*$ is therefore a linear function from $V^*$ to $\Bbb R$, and it’s defined by

$$v_0^*(f)=f(v_0)\tag{1}$$

for each $f\in V^*$. That is, its value at the linear functional $f\in V^*$ is simply the value of $f$ at $v_0$.

One does of course have to verify that the function from $V^*$ to $\Bbb R$ defined by $(1)$ actually *is* linear, but this is quite straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reading part issue was not 'vee-nought-star', but more something along the lines of 'the function determined by the vector $v_0$ on the functions $f$'... So it's the $v_0^*\,\text{here}(f)$ that is a problem verbalizing.

Comment: @Antoni: I read that the same way I read any function: ‘vee-nought-star of eff-star’ (or of $f$, if you don’t use the star to emphasize that it’s an element of $V^*$).

Comment: So is $v_0^*$ a function inhabiting the set of all linear functions in $V^*=\mathscr L(V,\mathbb F)$, which acting on a function $f^*$ which lives in the same space $V^*$  (all this unpacking the problem $v_0^*(f^*)$ expression), *is equal to* $f$, acting now as a variable (?), of $v_0$?

Comment: @Antoni: I guess that I shouldn’t have used $f^*$ instead of the original $f$ to emphasize that I was talking about a member of $V^*$. $v_0^*$ is a linear function from $V^*$ to $\Bbb R$; that’s what the members of $V^{**}$ are, just as the members of $V^*$ are linear functions from $V$ to $\Bbb R$. Each $v_0\in V$ determines one such functional, $v_0^*$, and if $V$ is finite-dimensional those are the only members of $V^{**}$. The functional $v_0^*$ acts on $V^*$ by sending an $f\in V^*$, which is a linear functional on $V$, to its value $f(v_0)$ at $v_0$.

Comment: Cutting through details, I see $V$ as arrows (I know they can also be polynomial, Fourier series), but just to get to the point... Arrows. $V^*$ would be the coefficients of the vector basis for $V$ (again, cutting through the complexity of Kronecker product, etc). So what "is" $V^{**}$? The way I read it is that $V=V^{**}$, but I know it's not so.

Comment: @Antoni: That point of view will not help you to understand what’s going on. The finite-dimensional vector spaces are simply too unrepresentative of vector spaces in general, and the double dual doesn’t really come into its own until you start looking at more interesting vector spaces. $V^*$ *is* the space of linear functionals on $V$. If $V$ is finite-dimensional one can represent it in terms of the coordinate functions for some basis for $V$, but that is an accidental byproduct of the fact that $V$ is finite-dimensional; in general there are linear functionals on $V$ that can’t be ...

Comment: ... represented that way. Then $V^{**}$ *is* the space of linear functionals on $V^*$, and it just happens, very nicely and neatly, that it contains a subspace isomorphic to $V$ by a very simple, natural isomorphism, the one that takes $v_0\in V$ to the functional $v_0^*\in V^{**}$. This is because the operation *evaluation at* $v_0$ on $V^*$ turns out to be linear, and evaluation at $v_0+v_1$ really does give you the sum of the values at $v_0$ and $v_1$, because the elements of $V^*$ are themselves linear functionals on $V$. But to get back to the main point, cutting through details in ...

Comment: ... the way you have in mind is a bad idea: it won’t give you a real understanding of the double dual and in fact will probably give you a somewhat mistaken view of it.

Comment: Both $V^*$ and $V^{**}$ map to a real number, is that number one and the same for a given vector $v_0$?

Comment: @Antoni: That question really does not make sense. The domain of a member of $V^*$ is $V$; the domain of a member of $V^{**}$ is $V^*$. Thus, ‘inputs’ to an $f\in V^*$ and a $\varphi\in V^{**}$ are completely different: $f$ sends each $v\in V$ to a real number, and $\varphi$ sends each $g\in V^*$ to a real number. Each $v_0\in V$ gives rise to a particular $\varphi=v_0^*\in V^{**}$, defined by $\varphi(f)=f(v_0)$ for each $f\in V^*$. The real number that this $\varphi$ assigns to any given $f\in V^*$ is the same real number that that $f$ assigns to the vector $v_0$ in the original space ...

Comment: ... $V$. If $V$ is finite-dimensional, it turns out that *every* $\varphi\in V^{**}$ is of this form, but in general that is far from being the case.

Comment: It just occurred to me that the confusion could be rather trivial: The elements of $V^*$ are functions, much like $f(x)=x^2$ is a function. **If** the function is actually evaluated at, say $x=2$, yielding $4$, we are in $V^{**}$: we've taken $f(x)=x^2$ as the input, and the output is its actual evaluation at $x=2$ (the original vector $v_0$). If this is correct, please let me know. Otherwise, just disregard - you helped me enough.

Comment: @Antoni: It’s close, but it’s not quite right. Let $v_0$ be a specific vector in $V$. The operation that assigns to each function $f\in V^*$ its value $f(v_0)$ at that specific point $v_0$ is a function from $V^*$ to $\Bbb R$, and that function is the one that we’ve been calling $v_0^*$. Evaluating $f$ at $v_0$ is not itself in $V^{**}$; the function on $V^*$ that evaluates *each* $f\in V^*$ at $v_0$ is the thing that’s in $V^{**}$.

Comment: I think I get it now: $v_0$ is fixed in $V^{**}$ and we just run through all the possible functions in $V^*$, which will yield different outputs in $\mathbb R$. In $V^*$ the function is fixed, and we need to build it, but in $V^{**}$ we run through all the possible linear maps from $v\in V$ to $\mathbb R$, and hence there is no need to build a basis.

Answer (score 1):

We might define a linear transformation $\theta : V \to V^{**}$ by the equation

$$ \theta(v)(f) = f(v) $$

The notation here is recursive; we are defining the linear transformation $\theta$ by specifying its value at every $v \in V$. In turn, we define the linear functional $\theta(v) \in V^{**}$ by specifying its value at every element $f \in V^*$.

To recap, the types of each subexpression are

- $\theta : V \to V^{**}$
- $v \in V$
- $f \in V^*$ (equivalently, $f : V \to \mathbb{R}$)
- $\theta(v) \in V^{**}$ (equivalently, $\theta(v) : V^* \to \mathbb{R}$)
- $\theta(v)(f) \in \mathbb{R}$
- $f(v) \in \mathbb{R}$

Now, some people don't like to use the usual function notation for function-valued functions. Here, the author is indicating the function via *decoration* — the author's notation $v^*$ means the same thing as my notation $\theta(v)$.

Another notation one might use for this is $v \mapsto (f \mapsto f(v))$. If you plug some value $v_0$ into this linear transformation, you get the linear functional $f \mapsto f(v_0)$.  (and if you then plug some linear functional $f_0$ into that, you get the number $f_0(v_0)$)

For some purposes, the most convenient notation is just $v$ written on the right (rather than on the left like functions "usually" are) — i.e. rather than rigidly interpret $f(v)$ as "the function $f$ evaluated at the value $v$", to have the mental flexibility to view it the other way around "$v$ evaluated at $f$", or even "the 'product' of $f$ and $v$", as needed. In many situations, if you can do this, you really don't need to distinguish between $V$ and $V^{**}$ so there is no problem using the same notation both for an element in $V$ and its corresponding element of $V^{**}$.

---

The reason for $v_0$, I think, is that the author wants you to think of it as an 'unspecified vector constant' rather than a 'vector-valued variable'. In my opinion there is no good reason to do so, but there may be some aspect of the author's choice of fine detail in mathematical grammar or the author's philosophical or pedagogical opinions that compels him to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (and +1). It offers a ton of granularity to the understanding of the notation, and *decoration* is very much in season over here... This thing with the V, V-star, and V-star-star is like riding a bike. Once it happens it's difficult to explain what's so difficult about it... Your answer is more targeted to the OP than the accepted post. However, Brian was incredibly patient in dispelling some incorrect interpretations, and if we can consider his comments as part of the answer, it probably should remain accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with a different example. Consider all maps from a set $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and push them together in a set, say $M(X,\mathbb{R})$.

This set can be given a structure of vector space by
$$
f+g\colon x\mapsto f(x)+g(x),
\qquad
\alpha f\colon x\mapsto \alpha f(x)
$$
for $f,g\in M(X,\mathbb{R})$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

If $X$ has more structure, then we may identify some useful subspaces of $M(X,\mathbb{R})$. For instance, if $X$ is a metric space, we could consider the *continuous* maps, $C(X,\mathbb{R})$; if $X$ is a differentiable manifold, we could consider the *infinitely differentiable* maps, $C^\infty(X,\mathbb{R})$; if $X$ is a measure space, we could consider the *integrable* maps $\mathscr{L}^1(X,\mathbb{R})$ or the *square integrable* maps $\mathscr{L}^2(X,\mathbb{R})$.

If we fix $x_0\in X$, we have an interesting map $e_{x_0}\colon M(X,\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$, simply defined by
$$
e_{x_0}(f)=f(x_0)
$$
Guess what? This map is *linear*. So we get a map, the *evaluation map*,
$$
e\colon X\to\operatorname{L}(M(X,\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})
\qquad
x_0\mapsto e_{x_0}
$$
The codomain is the set of all linear maps from $M(X,\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Yes, there is another example of interesting subspace I didn't mention before (on purpose). If $X=V$ is a *vector space*, then the set of linear maps $V\to\mathbb{R}$ is a subspace of $M(V,\mathbb{R})$. This is usually denoted by $V^*$, the *dual space* of $V$. So the map $e$ is
$$
e\colon X\to M(X,\mathbb{R})^*
$$

In all examples above, $e_{x_0}$ restricts to a map from the “interesting” subspace to $\mathbb{R}$ and so we can define an evaluation map, say,
$$
e\colon X\to\operatorname{L}(C^\infty(X,\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})=
C^\infty(X,\mathbb{R})^*
$$
in the case when $X$ is a differentiable manifold. Or, when $X=V$ is a vector space, an evaluation map
$$
e\colon V\to\operatorname{L}(V^*,\mathbb{R})=(V^*)^*=V^{**}
$$
Yes, in this case the codomain is now the dual of $V^*$. And, guess what? The map $e$ is *linear* (which is easy to prove).

How does the map work? Exactly in the same way as before: it is a particular case, after all: if $v_0\in V$, $e(v_0)$ is an element of $V^{**}$, that is, a linear map $V^*\to\mathbb{R}$; which one? Like before
$$
e\colon V\to V^{**}
$$
sends $v_0$ to $e_{v_0}$, which is defined by
$$
e_{v_0}(f)=f(v_0)
$$
which is exactly the same as saying $e_{v_0}=v_0^*$ as in your notes (although I'd not use a $^*$ here, but probably something like $\widehat{v_0}$).

Getting rid of the noughts, we have a map
$$
e\colon V\to V^{**},\quad v\mapsto e_v
$$
where $e_v(f)=f(v)$.

This can also be seen as a *bilinear* map $(v,f)\mapsto f(v)$, from $V\times V^*$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which has some interesting uses as well. But, concentrating on $e$, we see that it is injective (provided we accept that every vector space has a basis) and an isomorphisms precisely in the case when $V$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: +1 Thank you. There is a certain tautological quality to the mapping definition of $V^{**}$ that makes it slippery. I like the $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ notation, placing domains and codomains on equal footing.